# How to left pad a 2 dimensional byte array with leading zeros in C#

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2 dimensional byte array of a bitmap pixel data that I need to send to a thermal printer using ESC/POS via comport. I can do this successfully. However, I need to shift the printed image to the right. Center justify, Right justify, HT, and all other ESC/POS commands have no effect due to the command used to print the bitmap (DC2 * r n [d1.....dn]). 
I wish to left pad the array of bytes containing the bitmap in order to shift the printed image to the right. Below are my code lines to print bitmap

```
    private void Print_Bipmap()
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        int i;
        int RowBytes;
        byte n;
        Color Pixels;
        byte[,] ImageArray = new byte[bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height];

        // Calculate output size
        RowBytes = (bitmap.Width + 7) / 8;

        // Generate body of array
        for (y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y++)
        { // Each row...
            for (x = 0; x < (bitmap.Width / 8); x++)
            { // Each 8-pixel block within row...
                ImageArray[x, y] = 0;
                for (n = 0; n < 8; n++)
                { // Each pixel within block...
                    Pixels = bitmap.GetPixel(x * 8 + n, y);
                    if (Pixels.GetBrightness() < 0.5)
                    {
                        ImageArray[x, y] += (byte)(1 << (7 - n));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        comport_writeByte(18); //DC2
        comport_writeByte(42); //*
        comport_writeByte((byte)bitmap.Height); //r
        comport_writeByte((byte)RowBytes); //n

        for (y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y++)
        {
            for (x = 0; x < RowBytes; x++)
            {
              comport_writeByte(ImageArray[x, y]); //[d1 ..... dn]
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I left pad the 2 dimensional array (ImageArray[x, y])?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I would say you want left padding, but that is the smallest concern. What is not clean is if you want to resize the array (e.g. the n*r array would become (n+1)*r, having a column of 0-s on the left), or you only want to shift its contents. Also, it matters if you want to do the shift with a per-byte granularity (which probably means a shift by 8 pixels), or on bit-level (shifting by an arbitrary number of pixels)

Comment: @ tavemadar. Many thanks for your response. I would like to resize the array as shifting the contents may not achieve my goals. How do I do this?
Please take note of the edit.

Comment: For anyone may have the same need in future, see solution here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/288454aa-8e33-4b06-93ee-c8ac1a8fbcb3/how-to-left-pad-a-2-dimensional-byte-array-with-leading-zeros-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral&prof=required